# Radio button : difference between user click and programatic selection

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-store-apps

I have a group of 2 radio buttons and I need to know when the user clicks on one of them.
One of these 2 radio buttons must be selected by default (at page creation).

Why the check callback is called when I select the radiobutton from code? How can I differentiate them ? It bothers me since when the user perform the action, I must perform a web request, but when I select it from code at init time, it mustn't do any req.

```
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Search(ContractTextBox.Text, true);
}

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMainSearchItem.SubLevels}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid Margin="10">
                                                <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}" 
                                                    GroupName="ExclusiveGroupL3" 
                                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                    Checked="RadioButton_Checked"         
                                                    FontSize="18"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to deal with a situation like this is to define a `bool` property to use as a 'flag':

```
private bool isUserSelection = true;

...

private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isUserSelection) Search(ContractTextBox.Text, true);
}
```

And when you set the `CheckBox` value programmatically, set the flag to `false`:

```
isUserSelection = false;
SetCheckBoxValue(true);
isUserSelection = true;
```